# dynamic php xml image files attribute redifined error

Tags: php, xml, label

I am new to web developing and trying to make xml through php to be used in my flash gallery and getting this error when i am checking my php file:

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 3 at column 84: Attribute THUMB redefined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
// Set which extensions should be approved in the XML file
$extensions = array
(
  'jpg', 'JPG',
  'png', 'PNG',
  'gif', 'GIF',
  'bmp', 'BMP'
);

// Echo the header (XML)
header("Content-Type: text/xml");

// Prepare the XML file
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>' . "\r\n";
echo '<GALLERY COLUMNS="5" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="100">' . "\r\n";
$gallery = '<IMAGE FULL="';

// Get the files from the current directory
if (file_exists ("full_images/"))
{
  if (is_dir ("full_images/"))
  {
    $dh = opendir ("full_images/") or die (" Directory Open failed !");

    // Prepare the images array
    $imgs = array();
    while ($file = readdir ($dh))
    {
      // Only get the files ending with the correct extension
      if ( in_array( substr($file, -3), $extensions ) )
      {
        array_push($imgs, $file);
      }
    }
  closedir ($dh);
  }

  // Sort the array
  sort($imgs);

  foreach ($imgs as $img)
  {
    // Return all images in XML format
    $gallery.= 'full_image/' .$img . '" ' . 'THUMB="';
  }
}
// Get the files from the current directory
if (file_exists ("thumbs/"))
{
  if (is_dir ("thumbs/"))
  {
    $dh = opendir ("thumbs/") or die (" Directory Open failed !");

    // Prepare the images array
    $thumbs = array();
    while ($file = readdir ($dh))
    {
      // Only get the files ending with the correct extension
      if ( in_array( substr($file, -3), $extensions ) )
      {
        array_push($thumbs, $file);
      }
    }
  closedir ($dh);
  }

  // Sort the array
  sort($thumbs);

  foreach ($thumbs as $thumb)
  {
    // Return all images in XML format
    $gallery.= 'thumbs/' . $thumb;
  }
}
$gallery.= '" />';
$gallery.= "\r\n";
echo $gallery;
echo "</GALLERY>";
?>
```

where am i going wrong? and what is the solution? Thankyou.

Comment: As you can see with the syntax highlighting in your question, you have not written much code but much string. I would say this is the part you ask for "where am I going wrong." The solution is to fix the little error you did. Close the string instead of keeping it open.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r Only the syntax highlighter doesn't work...

Comment: If that is not the case, then the error message pretty precisely tells what is going wrong. The solution is to not add an attribute with the same name twice to the same element. XML does not support that.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r Exactly, now explain him where his error in the PHP-Code is.

Comment: The error is because of doing multiple things at once. That's complicated and it results in doing more errors.

Comment: What he wants is jumping from top to bottom... so, see my answer.

Comment: @bwoebi: Yes, certainly, however, your answer does not fix the problem to mix that many things. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16023809/2261774 for an example that modularizes a little more and aims for more code-reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($imgs as $img)
{
    // Return all images in XML format
    $gallery.= 'full_image/' .$img . '" ' . 'THUMB="';
}
```

This code part adds the attribute `THUMB` as many times as there are keys in $imgs.

You have to always create a new Image child element.

This would be the right code (supposing that thumb and image have the same name)

```
<?php
// Set which extensions should be approved in the XML file
$extensions = array
(
  'jpg', 'JPG',
  'png', 'PNG',
  'gif', 'GIF',
  'bmp', 'BMP'
);

// Echo the header (XML)
header("Content-Type: text/xml");

// Prepare the XML file
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>' . "\r\n";
echo '<GALLERY COLUMNS="5" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="100">' . "\r\n";
$gallery = '';

// Get the files from the current directory
if (file_exists ("full_images/"))
{
  if (is_dir ("full_images/"))
  {
    $dh = opendir ("full_images/") or die (" Directory Open failed !");

    // Prepare the images array
    $imgs = array();
    while ($file = readdir ($dh))
    {
      // Only get the files ending with the correct extension
      if ( in_array( substr($file, -3), $extensions ) )
      {
        array_push($imgs, $file);
      }
    }
  closedir ($dh);
  }

  // Sort the array
  sort($imgs);
}
// Get the files from the current directory
if (file_exists ("thumbs/"))
{
  if (is_dir ("thumbs/"))
  {
    $dh = opendir ("thumbs/") or die (" Directory Open failed !");

    // Prepare the images array
    $thumbs = array();
    while ($file = readdir ($dh))
    {
      // Only get the files ending with the correct extension
      if ( in_array( substr($file, -3), $extensions ) )
      {
        array_push($thumbs, $file);
      }
    }
  closedir ($dh);
  }

  // Sort the array
  sort($thumbs);

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgs); $i++)
  {
    // Return all images in XML format
    $gallery .= '<IMAGE FULL="full_image/'.$imgs[$i].'" THUMB="thumbs/' . $thumbs[$i].'"/>'."\r\n";
  }
}
echo $gallery;
echo "</GALLERY>";
?>
```

Comment: Well i tried your code and it is showing <GALLERY.....></GALLERY> label properly now (thankyou) but not spitting out the <IMAGE...../>. I mean it is not echoing $gallery at all. D:
And yes the thumbs and full images have same names.

Comment: '<GALLERY COLUMNS="5" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="100"></GALLERY>'
So you see..it is not echoing the $gallery at all..

Comment: @MuhammadAli Oh, there was a typo… (`$images` instead of `$imgs`) Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your patience. It is working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically your problem is given in the error message. Practically the problem is doing too many things at once. Instead simplify. For example obtaining files from a directory filtered by the extension *has been solved already* in large parts, you only need to add some little code:

```
class ListExtensions extends FilterIterator
{
    private $extensions;

    public function __construct($path, array $extensions = array()) {
        $this->extensions = $extensions;
        parent::__construct(new DirectoryIterator($path));
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/filteriterator.accept.php
     * @return bool true if the current element is acceptable, otherwise false.
     */
    public function accept() {
        /* @var $file SplFileInfo */
        $file = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return in_array($file->getExtension(), $this->extensions);
    }
}
```

This class allows you to easily traverse over the files with the extensions you specify. Because it all is encapsulated, your code is much more module. E.g. only in one part you concentrate on doing the directory listing and filtering, not in one part inside of another.

Similar for generating the XML. A library for that already exists, too. It takes care of creating the document, and as it knows XML you can not do that much wrong or even if, you will get noticed much earlier.

```
$extensions = array
(
    'jpg', 'JPG',
    'png', 'PNG',
    'gif', 'GIF',
    'bmp', 'BMP'
);

$largeFiles = new ListExtensions($pathFullImages, $extensions);
$thumbFiles = new ListExtensions($pathThumbImages, $extensions);

$pairs = new MultipleIterator();
$pairs->attachIterator($largeFiles);
$pairs->attachIterator($thumbFiles);

$gallery = new SimpleXMLElement('<GALLERY COLUMNS="5" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="100"/>');

foreach ($pairs as $pair)
{
    $image = $gallery->addChild('IMAGE');

    $image['FULL']  = "full_image/$pair[0]";
    $image['THUMB'] = "thumbs/$pair[1]";
}

// Serve XML incl. header
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$gallery->asXML('php://output');
```

Comment: Yes, surely this fixes the problem; but I'm really unsure that the TO will understand what you are doing ;) (my code only fixes the problem without rewriting everything...)

Comment: @bwoebi: Well, at least you could create a function that does the reading of a directory into the array. The orignal code has doubled it, that means, you need to maintain the same code two-times while not doing any difference between the two.

Comment: i am completely out of the circle here, i am sorry. It gives meh this error now:
**Fatal error: Class 'ListExtensions' not found in /..../..../public_html/flash_gallery/backhand.php on line 10**

as i mentioned before i am new to web developing specially to php and xml so i would appreciate if you just give me a link that describes this code more briefly? Thankyou.

Comment: @MuhammadAli you naturally must include the code above too (which starts with `class`...) ;)

Comment: i already did that but then it is showing meh just a big pile of errors :o

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Directory name must not be empty.' in /.../..../public_html/flash_gallery/backhand.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /.../.../public_html/flash_gallery/backhand.php(8): DirectoryIterator->__construct('') #1 /.../.../public_html/flash_gallery/backhand.php(30): ListExtensions->__construct(NULL, Array) #2 {main} thrown in /..../..../public_html/flash_gallery/backhand.php on line 8

This is the error that it is showing after adding the class

Comment: @MuhammadAli It'd be an idea to define `$pathFileImages` and `$pathThumbImages`